# El Objeto ya esta en uso, al guardar imagen en C#

Tags: c#, aforge

tengo un botón que guarda la imagen de mi camara, de la siguiente manera:

```
 MemoryStream photo = new MemoryStream();
 pictureBox1.Image.Save(photo , ImageFormat.Jpeg);
 byte[] byte_photo = photo.GetBuffer();
```

Despues guardo en la base de datos mi arreglo de bytes, cuando el usuario pulsa de manera continua el botón me arroja el siguiente error:

```
El objeto ya está en uso.
en System.Drawing.Image.get_Width()
en System.Drawing.Image.get_Size()
en System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.ImageRectangleFromSizeMode(PictureBoxSizeMode mode)
en System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
en System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
en System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
en System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
```

Para Intentar solucionar utilice Await y Async, de la siguiente manera:

```
     async Task<string> task_photo()
    {  
        MemoryStream photo = new MemoryStream();
        pictureBox1.Image.Save(photo , ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        byte[] byte_photo = photo.GetBuffer();
        var idphoto = ObjectId.Empty;
        idphoto = fs.UploadFromBytes("nombre_archivo", byte_photo);
        return idphoto;
    }

   async void crearEmpleado(string idEmployee, string nombre)
    {
       // Mando a llamar mi Task
       string don = await task_photo();
       // Donde don es lo que me Retorna
    }
```

Desafortunadamente el problema es el mismo, ya que me envia el mismo error(Objeto en uso...),pero como warning en mi VS tengo:

```
    This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously.
    Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, 
    or   'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.
```

Estuve leyendo un poco, al parecer el objeto ya no esta en memoria, pero no se como solucionarlo....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que el problema si te fijas bien es que el thread de ejecución de la UI está accediendo a la imagen y tú también estas accediendo a la misma imagen desde otro hilo. GDI+ no permite que dos hilos accedan a la vez a un bitmap. 
Si necesitas convertir tu imagen a un array de bytes puedes hacer lo siguiente usando la clase `ImageConverter`

```
public static byte[] ImageToByte(Image img)
{
    ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
    return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, he aceptado tus aportes como validos

Answer (score 2):

Esta es la manera en que resolvi mi problema, gracias a los aportes de @Sergio

```
    public static byte[] ImageToByte2(Image img)
    {
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[0];
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            img.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            stream.Close();
            byteArray = stream.ToArray();
        }
        return byteArray;
    }
```

Y solo lo mando a llamar de la siguiente manera:

```
   byte[] foto = ImageToByte2(pictureBox1.Image);
```